# Question closed without any explanation (and I'm always searching for an answer)

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

Some days ago, I wrote this question: [Screenshot takes a long time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386012/screenshot-takes-a-long-time).

The post was closed as

> **closed** as unclear what you're asking by [5 different users] Aug 14 at 13:36
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question.

So ok, maybe my question needs improvements, but I don't know what improvements since I'm not a Unix master in fact...
Also, nobody helps me find out where does my questions needs improvements or where I made an error writing my question; so It's difficult for me to do better ^^'

I always have my problem of too long time to take screenshot on my computer, and I don't find anything on Internet and also here on Unix stackexchange. Maybe I missed something, but for now, I'm just lost with my problem.

Can you explain me what was wrong with my question; in order to I can improve it or rewrite it if just improving will not help you to find clues to solve my problem ?
Thank you for your help ! And if you need more information, please ask for them, and not just flag my post as unclear; it's not helping me very well. I'm ready to improve the description of the problem as many as needed; to finally fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First rule of making great questions is to ask yourself...

*What am I trying to say? and what is my reader going to understand from that?*

Ok, you have problems with your screenshots... but what else? have you hardware issues? software issues? which methods have you already tried? is there some error when you take a screenshot? some output? have you tried to debug the info? what have you already looked for? have you any idea of what's going on? what is the exact procedure that you use to take a screenshot?

as you can see... a lot of questions can arise from a very simple problem... and for us is hard to try to figure out what's happening with only one approach...

now to your problem... I can see that there are some comments of people trying to help you, so I believe that the rest comes up to you, we are here to help, not to solve the problem. We can point a direction and is up to you to try harder and find the very best solution... It happens a lot here that people seek only for a quick solution and they don't want to learn and become even better... so you need to understand that there are hundreds of bad questions and bad answers, but we do our best to try to help...

I really hope that you will be able to find your solution and learn in the process, good luck :)

PS. give shutter or any other software for screenshots a try ;) maybe it will help you to make it faster as the problems are with the keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Thank for your answer. I know that things (I'm big stackoverflow user in fact); and in this case, I explain all I know about my problem: What I can see of the problem, how I do to get the error, and that I don't know what kind of command or anything could be used as a clue to fix the problem. The comments was posted after my post was reopen, and now I'm ok to discuss about this problem and slowly find a solution with the help of the community :)